# Ruby how to use ActiveRecord join result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have joined 3 tables like

```
result = A.joins("INNER JOIN B B1 ON A.id = B1.A_id")
          .joins("INNER JOIN B B2 on A.id = B2.A_id")
          .where("B1.key" => "B1", "B2.key" => "B2")
```

how to retrieve objects A, B1, B2 separately? Like this?

```
result.map {|res|
  A = res.A
  B1 = res.B1
  B2 = res.B2
}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `includes` to preload the records from your associations. Alternatively, you can use join and then `preload` your associations. You can also use `pluck` methods which would pull particular fields from the tables, like so:

`A.joins(...).pluck("table_name1.field_name, table_name2.field_name, table_name3.field_name")`